# How do I remove commas from an array of strings in python?

Tags: python-2.7

I am working with a data set (and simultaneously trying to get better at python). Imported as a csv file one column of data has a dtype of object. I am trying to convert them to floats so that I can further manipulate the data, etc.

The numbers have commas in them and so don't seem to be able to go straight from objects to floats or objects to strings to floats. My next thought was "oh, i'll just take out the commas!" but even that is proving more difficult than I thought.

Here is the code I have so far, the next trouble is taking out the commas and creating a new array...:

```
 def remcom(x):
     s = np.array(())
     for line in x:
         s[i] = re.sub(',','',line)
     return s
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You should post an example input & output. Further, should we assume that `np` is `numpy` ?

Comment: How are you importing as a csv file?  Python has a builtin csv module which might make this easier

Comment: np is numpy, sorry. I am importing the csv file in pandas - pandas.read_csv('c:\file.csv')

Comment: Looked up how to do this using pandas tool and found the answer in seconds.... thanks foon

Comment: If you found a solution, you can (please) answer your own question.